# How to compare two table column values using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Need only differing rows values from two tables

Like..

```
ID  Name    Salary
1   ABC     2000
2   XYZ     4000
3   Suresh  6000

ID  Name    Salary
1   ABC     3000
2   XYZ     5000
3   Suresh  6000
```

If I update first table, here I saved particular row in destination table from source table based on condition, now I want to compare two table's column values.. Which column values are updated... Please help me

```
 ID    OldSalary       NewSalary
  1      2000             3000
  2      4000             5000
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
select newTable.ID, oldTable.Salary as OldSalary, newTable.Salary as NewSalary
from oldTable 
    join newTable on oldTable.ID = newTable.ID
where oldTable.Salary <> newTable.Salary;
```